# Rails - Issue with Create (Active Record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to insert data in the table using Create method. However I am facing two issues -

1. One of the timestamp column is not appearing on the actual query.
2. I get an error - Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

The data is read from the file uploaded by user.

The logic where I am setting up the column values is -

```
chat_date_time = date_sent + " " + time_sent
data_array.push({:username => user,:chat_timestamp => chat_date_time ,:name => name,:sent_text => sent_text})
$prev_date_time_sent = date_sent + " "+ time_sent
$prev_name = name
```

The message spat out by Rails -

> (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "chat_data_regulars" ("username", "name", "sent_text", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["username", "544cd2520b9b22a18fcedd34c544a8da"], ["name", "Tushar Saurabh"], ["sent_text", "You gave your mentee critical feedback"], ["created_at", "2016-05-12 03:47:35.018330"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-12 03:47:35.018330"]]
>      (13.6ms)  commit transaction
>      (0.2ms)  begin transaction
>      (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14077ms (ActiveRecord: 15.5ms)

If you see, the INSERT statement doesnt have the column chat_timestamp, even though I am explicitly populating the value in code.
Also,the error i am getting is -

**Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):**

The data is read from a file, that has UTF-8 chars but the line it is reading doesnt. I am using sqlite as db.

Below is the schema of table -

> CREATE TABLE "chat_data_regulars" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "username" varchar, "chat_timestamp" datetime, "name" varchar, "sent_text" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);

Comment: Maybe you should just create instance of DateTime class and assign day, month, year, hour separately and then assign it to your model.

Comment: @Mr.D, i used :chat_timestamp => DateTime.new, and in the actual query spat out by rails had chat_timestamp column included. However the issue "Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)" still persists.